# Updating Options of Flexslider in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

Flexslider has before function Fires asynchronously with each slider animation

`//before: function(){}, //Callback: function(slider)`

Trying to update its [options](https://gist.github.com/warrendholmes/9481310) at functions.php but callback api functions are not working

```
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options', 'ud_update_woo_flexslider_options');

function ud_update_woo_flexslider_options( $options ) {

      $options['slideshow'] = true; // It works

    **$options['before'] = "function(slider){alert('something')}";** // Not working

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: have you checked plugin file for options, how they are working with callback function

Comment: what is the name called for plugin file for options ?

Comment: did you solve this? I've having the same problem